# Combine two column into single column in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have one table (suppose `tableA`) in Postgres sql consist of two column with the same type (that is `bigint`), for example `columnA` and `columnB`. Is it possible for me to combine these two column into a single column. So the data from `columnA` appended after data from `columnB` and the resulted data used as input for `in` statement?

For example my syntax was:

```
update tableA set columnC = 12 where columnC in 
(<appended result from column A and columnB>)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. Your obfuscated table and column names don't make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is your goal, but - maybe this will be helpful. In PostgreSQL you can define your own composite types, for example:

```
CREATE TYPE mytype(col1 bigint, col2 bigint);
```

Next you can use it in the definition of a table

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, x mytype);
```

or create values on the fly, just like that:

```
SELECT (columnA, columnB)::mytype FROM tableA
```